# Password Reset Form missing in template with reseting in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Project and there is an API app with Django Rest Framework. When the user tries to reset the button they receive the email with the link but when it is clicked the url shows only the reset button without the password reset form.

Here is the urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='user')
```

Here is the Django settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ]
}
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER':
        'api.serializers.PasswordResetSerializer',
}
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS=['users.models.EmailBackend']
```

If I am using the default way to reset the password why is it showing a the password_reset_confirm.html without the form. I am sure the form is working as I tested it without DRF.

Comment: Try checking view names, template names and configuration settings, and template and view names accordingly in the config file.

Comment: I think you should consider looking into `urls.py` - you can try to see how it's done here:  https://dev.to/earthcomfy/django-reset-password-3k0l